# saving and transfering data from one text file to another

Tags: file-io, char, fopen, fclose, fgetc

Having problems with transferring a data from one text file to another. My idea is to transfer it per character but it seems to not be working. I have added these codes at the beginning

```
FILE *addressPtr;
FILE *ressPtr;
```

and

```
addressPtr = fopen("temporary.txt","w");
```

These set of codes are in a switch condition

```
fclose(addressPtr);
addressPtr = fopen("temporary.txt","r");
while((filechar = fgetc(addressPtr)) != EOF){
    fclose(addressPtr);
    ressPtr = fopen("Address Book.txt","a");
    fprintf(ressPtr,"%c",filechar);
    fclose(ressPtr);
    addressPtr = fopen("temporary.txt","r");
}
printf("The file has been successfully saved!!");
```

I just learned about these file operations and dont really know what went wrong

If I open my Address Book.txt file it will only display the first character of my temporary.txt but continuously (never-ending).

Comment: Each time you close the file and reopen it, it starts from the beginning. You do not need to close one file in order to write to a different one; just keep both files open until all of the input is exhausted, and then close them.

Answer (score -1):

You need to open the files in `binary` mode.

```
addressPtr = fopen("temporary.txt","wb");
```

also write in binary mode using `"rb"` to open the file.

I'm not sure why you're using `fopen` inside a loop. But if you want to copy a file then this is some working code I've tested:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *addressPtr;
    FILE *ressPtr;
    char filechar = '\0';

    addressPtr = fopen("D:\\test\\source.jpg","rb");
    ressPtr = fopen("D:\\test\\dest.jpg","wb");

    while(!feof(addressPtr))
    {
        filechar = fgetc(addressPtr);
        fprintf(ressPtr,"%c",filechar);
    }
    fclose(addressPtr);
    fclose(ressPtr);
    printf("The file has been successfully saved!!");

}
```

This essentially copies a file called `source.jpg` to another file called `dest.jpg`.

Hope you got your answer.